# Prevent duplicate form submissions while awaiting a response Flask Python

Tags: python, pandas, flask, flask-wtforms

I am running a large request via API and massaging some data before the user sees it. I am looking to prevent the user from clicking the download button while all this information is processed. What would be the best way to accomplish this through a Flask Form?

Here is my HTML:

```
<form method="POST"> 
          <button type="submit" name="download" value="download" class="button is-primary is-light">Download</button>
          {% if error_statement %}
              <article class="message is-danger">
                <div class="message-body">
                  {{ error_statement }}
                </div>
              </article>
              {% endif %}
        </form>
```

Here is my Flask Form:

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import *
from flask import (
    Flask,
    g,
    redirect,
    render_template,
    request,
    session,
    url_for,
    flash,
    Response
)


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret'


@app.route('/home', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def home():
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    submit = SubmitField('Download')
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyForm() 
    if request.form['download'] == 'download':
        #At this point I have code where I call a bunch of APIs and convert data to a CSV file
        #This process takes anywhere between 1-3 minutes to complete
        if not final_df.empty:
             today = date.today()
             return Response(final_df.to_csv(index=False, header=True), mimetype="text/csv", headers={"Content-disposition": "attachment; filename=export" + today.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") + ".csv"})
       else:
            error_statement = 'Something Went Wrong Please Try Again'
            return render_template("login.html", error_statement=error_statement)
    return render_template('home.html', form=form)
return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Can anyone provide guidance on how to prevent the user from clicking the download button while my data is processed?

Comment: I assume it's more of UI related stuff, I also got into the same situation. I added spinner at the HTML of the button till I get the response back from the flask endpoint. Once I receive the response I then remove the spinner CSS from the button. I think This might help.
https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/spinner

Comment: Thanks for the feedback here but does this prevent the user from clicking on the button while the spinner is visible? The problem I am running is that if the user clicks twice, it starts the process again which I want to avoid.

Comment: May be you should try disabling the button during the time of processing. Once you got the status from the API, just enable it once again or something like that. It's just something you can do using JS.

Comment: Yup, I took your advice and that's what I ended up doing. Thanks!